# Primefaces selectOneMenu opens only once

Tags: primefaces, selectonemenu

I'm facing a strange behavior: a Primeface selectOneMenu opens only once. After the menu is closed for the first time I can't open it again... Replacing the 'p' in  with 'h' will show the default menu which works perfectly fine.

EDIT:

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>

 <f:view xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
       xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"
       xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
       xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
       xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
       xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
       <h:head />
       <h:body> 
             <p:selectOneMenu value="#{...}"> 
                 <f:selectItem itemLabel="less than 98%" itemValue="less than 98%" />  
                 <f:selectItem itemLabel="98 - 99,5%" itemValue="98 - 99,5%" />  
                 <f:selectItem itemLabel=">= 99,5%" itemValue=">= 99,5%" />   
             </p:selectOneMenu> 
      </h:body>
 </f:view>
```

Does anyone know what do to?

Thank you in advance :)

PS: I'm using Chrome web browser

Comment: How can we help you without seeing your code? XHTML and BackBean Code .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It had to do with jQuery which wasn't properly added to the project.